# Using durable nonce to reach higher transaction succes

Tags: transactions, swap, priority-fees, durable-nonce

As the network is congested, many tx fail to be executed by the cluster, even with an insane priority fees (0.03+). look like this is due to block hash saturation.
Now I wonder if by working with durable nonce, we could make tx succeed 100%?
I haven't done much research/testing with durable nonce yet, but I'd like to open a discussion about it.

What do you think of this approach?

For instance : pre-creating a pool of durable nonce account, store it, and use it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Using a nonce account won't make a difference when it comes to a higher probability of landing your transaction.

Nonce accounts simply allow you to sign a static, fixed blockhash rather than a blockhash from the network that lives less long using `getLatestBlockhash`.

Let's go through how they operate: if you want any transaction to land, you create your message, sign it with a blockhash, and then submit it to the network. When you submit it, it may not arrive at the leader because your connection does not have enough stake, or it may arrive at the leader and have its priority fee priced too low, so the leader skips it in favor of more lucrative transactions.

If you notice that your transaction hasn't landed in a few blocks, you can try sending it again, in the hope that another leader will process it. You keep trying this every few blocks, until your transaction's blockhash expires, which means that your transaction will never be processed. You need to fetch a new blockhash, re-sign the transaction, and start all over again.

A nonce account simply removes the step where you need to fetch a new blockhash and re-sign the transaction. You'll still need to keep broadcasting your transaction until it lands.