# My transactions are lost

Tags: solana-program, send-transaction, missing

I'm running an application that sends Sol and some tokens to wallet. But even I didn't get any error on the preflight, few of my transactions are keep missing.

I spending **3M microlamports** for compute unit price and using recentblockhash from **finalized** commitment.

Is there any solutions to make my transactions perfectly load in block?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a deal with the leader proposing the block, there's no way to totally guarantee that your transaction will land.

Copying from another answer at [Using durable nonce to reach higher transaction succes](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12014/using-durable-nonce-to-reach-higher-transaction-succes/12107#12107):

> If you want any transaction to land, you create your message, sign it with a blockhash, and then submit it to the network. When you submit it, it may not arrive at the leader because your connection does not have enough stake, or it may arrive at the leader and have its priority fee priced too low, so the leader skips it in favor of more lucrative transactions.

> If you notice that your transaction hasn't landed in a few blocks, you can try sending it again, in the hope that another leader will process it. You keep trying this every few blocks, until your transaction's blockhash expires, which means that your transaction will never be processed. You need to fetch a new blockhash, re-sign the transaction, and start all over again.